# tensorflow - Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, resnet

I installed anaconda, created a fresh new environment and installed tensorflow via pip.
Then I tried this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.applications.ResNet152V2(
    include_top=True,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None,
    pooling=None,
    classes=1000,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
)
```

And i directly got:

```
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "tensorflow/python/framework/cpp_shape_inference.proto":
  tensorflow.CppShapeInferenceResult.HandleShapeAndType.specialized_type: ".tensorflow.SpecializedType" is not defined.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The code just works fine on Google_colab

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.applications.resnet_v2.ResNet152V2(
    include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000,
    classifier_activation='softmax'
)
```

Output

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/resnet/resnet152v2_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
242753536/242745792 [==============================] - 3s 0us/step
242761728/242745792 [==============================] - 3s 0us/step
<keras.engine.functional.Functional at 0x7faf1736c210>
```

Issue is with Protobuf insatallation

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install --no-binary protobuf protobuf
```

Comment: Got the following error:  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.core.framework.types_pb2' has no attribute '_SPECIALIZEDTYPE'

Comment: This is sooo helpful!!! Thank you.

Comment: I was having issues with error : "TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly." this was happening on a docker container running tensorflow and this answer helped me solve the problem.